# QPixmap hover effect?

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

I need to add a "hover effect" to some `QPixmaps` added to a `QGraphicsScene`. I would like to "highlight" my `QPixmap` by filling it with a halfway transparent white color when the user hovers over it. If at all possible I want to avoid using the `setPixmap(QPixmap)` method to exchange my pixmap with a premade "hover image".
This is what I've got so far:

```
import com.trolltech.qt.gui.QGraphicsPixmapItem;
import com.trolltech.qt.gui.QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent;
import com.trolltech.qt.gui.QPixmap;

public class SelectablePixmapItem extends QGraphicsPixmapItem {

    private QPixmap pixmap;

    public SelectablePixmapItem(QPixmap pixmap) {
        super(pixmap);
        setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
        setItemPixmap(pixmap);
    }

    private void setItemPixmap(QPixmap pixmap) {
        this.pixmap = pixmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent e) {
    }
}
```

**Update:** it does capture the events by the way :)

Comment: Does your version of Qt Jambi have [QGraphicsEffects](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicseffect.html)?

Comment: Yes. It does......... sorry for the many dots. Word minimum :)

Comment: Why don't you just draw a transparent rectangle (e.g. `QColor(255, 255, 255, 128)`) over the image? It will probably be faster than QGraphicsEffects.

Comment: How would I so so? I have tried doing that using the fill method of QPixmap but filling it with that color will replace the pixels, not add them as a extra layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the coordinates of the pixmap, you can do:

```
graphicsscene.addRect(pixmap.rect(),
                      new QPen(),
                      new QBrush(new QColor(255, 255, 255, 128)));
```

to create a transparent white rectangle on top of the pixmap.

(Sorry if my Java is bad, I am adapting what I know from PyQt style).

Comment: Thank you so much! With minor modifications to your code the implementation worked! :D